# Can iOS/Android apps work with Linux Servers?

Tags: android, ios, linux

I'm looking at developing an app for iOS and Android that requires a server in order to work (this has to do with a group I'm connected with on a college campus). So I have been trying to find out if iOS apps can run off a Linux server before I spend anything on one. However, I have not been able to find this information anywhere. So, does anyone know if an iOS app requires an iOS server or will a Linux server work just fine? Moreover, if I require an iOS server, could an android app work with an iOS server?

I'm not trying to be cheap with this, I'm just trying to keep the group from having to spend more than they have to.

Comment: any kind of server will do, it all depends on the protocol with which the client will be communicating with that server. If you ware going to use webservice with JSON any modern platform will be able to use it.

Answer (score 6):

There's no such as an iOS server or Android server. iOS apps run on iOS devices. Android apps run on Android devices. iOS and Android (as well as just about any other client) can connect to any server that provides an interface. It doesn't matter if the server is running Linux, OS X, Windows, or any other OS.

Your server just needs to provide a public interface - typically through some sort of web server.

But the iOS and Android apps will not run on the server. They will make network calls to the server.

tl;dr - yes, an iOS or Android app will have no problem accessing your Linux server.

Comment: Thanks! I was obviously thinking about servers incorrectly then.